# Excluding custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, conditional-tags

I'm attempting to develop an `is_blog()` function which returns true if the current view is a single post, blog home, or post archive. I have successfully excluded pages and attachments. My current code is in my theme's `functions.php`, as follows:

```
function is_blog() {
    global $post;
    $post_type = get_post_type( $post );

    // is_archive() covers is_author(), is_category(), is_date(), is_tag(), and is_tax()
    return ( ('page' == $post_type ) && !is_attachment() && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_single() ) );
}
```

So far, this works as expected per the above criteria - for this development I call the function from my `footer.php` and display the result.

My current difficulty is custom types. I have one custom type currently, and the function returns `true`, even though the custom type view is certainly not blog-related. I'm aware of checking for the post type, as evidenced by the code (oddly, a single post has a type of 'page'), but how can I exclude as yet-unknown custom types? Sure, I have just one now, but I'd like to be able to prevent ANY custom type from causing a `true` result.

Is there any way to catch ANY type that is not built-in to WordPress?

Comment: is_archive returns true for CPT archives, so I'd use the is_category, is_tag... instead. you could use is_singular('post') instead of is_single

Answer (score 1):

This function could help you filter out non standard post types:

```
function is_non_standard_type($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        // rewind_posts();
        global $post;
        $id = $post->ID;
    }
    $post_type = get_post_type( $id );

    return in_array($post_type, array('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'nav_menu, 'nav_menu_item', 'revision')); // You might want to handle revision differently
}
```

Keep in mind though that this is basically only true for single pages (i.e. `is_single() === true`), and even then you can't be entirely certain. This is due to the fact that the global `$post` might change during the course of loading the page, depending on what happens during any loops. For example, a loop in a sidebar might overwrite the value of `$post`. To account for this you could use `rewind_posts()` to revert to the state the global query/post was in when the page started loading.

But then there are also archive pages, for which the `$post` variable might not hold anything or might not reflect a single post type. Take taxonomy pages for example - as they taxonomies are not unique to a single post type you can't really be sure that just because you are querying `taxonomy_x` you will only get posts of type `post_type_y`. You might be able to work around this by using a function such as the below, but it will only work if the query being run has the `post_type` defined, which it might not always be.

```
function queried_post_type_object() {
    $var = get_query_var('post_type');

    if ($var) {
        return get_post_type_object($var);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Even if you do manage to correctly determine which post type, taxonomies etc. are being displayed, the logic involved will not be trivial. Finding the right combination of `is_single()`, `is_archive()` in combination with exception for different post types will probably pose a challenge, but with a bit of work you should be able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

For archives that aren't post type archives:

```
// if is an archive but NOT a post type archive:
if( is_archive() && ! is_post_type_archive() )
    echo 'blog archive';
```

For single posts that are only of post type `post`, use instead of `is_single()`:

```
if( is_singular( 'post' ) )
    echo 'blog post';
```